# Python - wifi - reauth ap

Tags: python, web, wifi

Long story short.
Having some problems with some coding in python.

working on a program to spoof mac address and open new trial session on ap,
(this is for education only.)

the program works with ap that has free 1 hour pass.
the program works like this:
shuts off the wifi adapter
runs .bat script, which changes mac address to random mac address.
turns wifi back on.
opens browser and sends login through with new mac address.
repeats every 1 hour.

the problem:
I am able to shut dowm, change address and bring back up. but,
how do i get the new address in a var and pass it through a web browser to re auth myself.
and open a new session of the trial?

```
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
import os
import time

def main():
    wifidown()
    changemac()
    wifiup()
    reauth()
    time.sleep(3600)

def wifidown():
    os.system("wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=7 call disable")

def changemac():
    os.system("C:\Users\username\somewhere\theprogram\theprogram.bat")

def wifiup():
    os.system("wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=7 call enable")

def reauth():
    url = 'https://server.name.com/anothername/?client-mac=mymacaddress&ap-mac=addressofap&hash=somehasvaluethatpassesthrough'
    values = {'plan' : 'trial',
              'zip code' : '12345',
              'e mail' : 'anemail@someemail' }

    data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
    data = data.encode('utf-8')
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, data)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    the_page = response.read()

while True:
    main()
```

Thank you.

Update**

Yes it helps. I was trying to do this way.

```
macid = "01:02:03:04:05:06"
mac = "?client-mac=" + macid
apid = "01:02:03:04:05:06"
ap = "&ap-mac=" + apid
hashid = "8JTsXjOC7jcCppExAqbsBmFF4kNMePA6wgrMaMI6MLDUO6bZsc8tgQMfEfGY%2Bp9aLEdXfTZCapb%2B93DotAFLlQ%3D%3D"
thehash = "&hash=" + hashid
url = 'https://the.ap.server.website/' + mac + ap + thehash

def main():
    wifidown()
    changemac()
    wifiup()
    urlfunction()
    time.sleep(3600)

def wifidown():
    os.system("wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=7 call disable")

def changemac():
    os.system("C:\Users\esc_fn\Desktop\macchanger\macchange.bat")

def urlfunction():
    webbrowser.open_new(url)

def wifiup():
    os.system("wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=7 call enable")

while True:
    main()
```

the ap uses a script called purchase.js to get the form data and send it.
the code for that is.

```
var pdate = new Date();
var offerlink = basepath + 'terms/';

$(document).ready(function(){
// Hide Sponsored Access form
$('#complimentary_spn').hide();
$('#xsubad').hide();

$('a#inline').fancybox({
    hideOnContentClick: false,
    showCloseButton: false,
    margin: 0,
    padding: 0
});

$('a.iframe').fancybox({
    hideOnContentClick: false,
    showCloseButton: false,
    scrolling: 'no',
    margin: 0,
    padding: 0,
    height: 510
});

$('#triggerComplete').fancybox({
    hideOnContentClick: false,
    showCloseButton: false,
    margin: 0,
    padding: 0
});

$('#rateplanid').change(function(){
    // Clear all errors
    clear_all_errors('#messageBox');

    var planid = $(this).val();
    if (planid > 0)
    {
        $('#complimentary_spn').fadeOut('fast');
        $('#xsubad').fadeOut('fast');
        $('#paid').fadeIn('fast');

        // Set offer and restrictions link
        $('#offerlink').find('.pop').attr('href', offerlink+'ppu');
    }
    else
    {
        $('#paid').fadeOut('fast');
        $('#complimentary_spn').fadeIn('fast');

        if ($.inArray(planid, do_reg) < 0)
            $('#xsubad').fadeIn('fast');

        // Set offer and restrictions link
        $('#offerlink').find('.pop').attr('href', offerlink+planid);
    }

    // Set plan cookie to expire in 10 minutes
    pdate.setTime(pdate.getTime() + (10 * 60 * 1000));
    setCookie('planid', planid, pdate, '/', '', '');

    // Reset required fields
    set_required_fields();

    // Disable submit buttons
    check_enable_submit();

    $(this).blur();
});

// Set default plan
if (getCookie('planid'))
    $('#rateplanid').val(getCookie('planid'));
else if (planid)
    $('#rateplanid').val(planid);

// Trigger change to set required fields
$('#rateplanid').trigger('change');

$("#pwreset").click(function(){
    $.post(
        basepath + 'ajax/resetpw',
        {
            username: $('#resetuser').val()
        },
        function(data) {
            if (data == '')
            {
                $.fancybox.close();
                return;
            }

            set_error('resetuser', data);
        }
    );
});

$('input, select').not('#resetuser').change(function(){
    $.post(
        actionurl+'/validate',
        $('#purchaseForm').serialize() + '&key=' + $(this).attr('name'),
        function(data) { validate_done(data) }
    );
});

$('input.submitOrderButton, input.startSessionButton').click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('opaque'))
        return;

    $.post(
        actionurl+'/validate',
        $('#purchaseForm').serialize(),
        function(data) { validate_done(data) }
    );
});
});

// Override validation error
validate_error = function(json_data)
{
//console.info('purchase.validate_error');

try
{
    if (json_data.errors.nobilling)
    {
        // Pop payment form
        $('.iframe').click()
        return;
    }

    $.each(json_data.errors, function(key, msg) {
        set_error(key, msg);
    });

    window.location.hash = '#messageBox';
}
catch (e)
{
    console.error('purchase.validate_error - %s - %s', e.name, e.message);
}
};

// Override validation success
validate_success = function(json_data)
{
//console.info('purchase.validate_success');

try
{
    var planid = $('#rateplanid').val();

    // For Sponsored Access, perform login
    if ($.inArray(planid, ['spn']) >= 0)
    {
        do_login();
        return;
    }

    // For paid access, pop confirmation screen
    $('#completePopup').html(json_data.data.pophtml);
    $('#triggerComplete').click();

    // Track with Omniture
    var s = s_gi('comcastwificaptiveportalprod');
    s.tl(this,'o','Payment Confirmation Desktop Page');

    return;
}
catch (e)
{
    console.error('purchase.validate_success - %s - %s', e.name, e.message);
}
};

var confirmed = function()
{
$.fancybox.close();
do_login();
};

 var set_required_fields = function()
 {
  //console.info('purchase.set_required_fields');

// Clear required fields
$('.required').removeClass('required');

var planid = $('#rateplanid').val();
if (planid > 0)
{
    // Set required fields
    $('input#username, input#password, input#password1, input#password2').addClass('required');
    $('input#firstname, input#lastname, input#email').addClass('required');
    $('#paymentFormInputs1, #paymentFormInputs2').find(':input').each(function() {
          $(this).not('#storeinfo').addClass('required');
    });
}
else
{
    // Set required fields
    $('#complimentary_'+planid).find(':input').each(function() {
      $(this).addClass('required');
    });
}
};
```

My question is:

how do I get the new mac address in the variable called macid
how do I get the ap mac address in the variable apid 
how do I get the hash it is asking for and put it in the variable hashid
how do I send the appropriate form data through. ie.. plan id.

Comment: it's impossible to tell how to re-auth through the web if you haven't provided more details how that re-auth web works.

Comment: just updated the question

Answer (score 0):

You just need to auth yourself on the authentication server right? I think process of authentication and re-authentication is the same. Recommend using `requests` module. Here is [link](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication/) for you.

Try authentication code like this:

```
>>> from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
>>> requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))
<Response [200]>
```

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: @daugherjo If this answer helps, just accept it please. If you have further question, please ask another question so that others might not get confused with this not related answer. :)